# \pdfstrcmp or \strcmp in pure TeX

Tags: tex-core, latex3, pdfstrcmp

I'm trying to get LaTeX3 working with an old e-TeX kernel, and it fails due to the lack of `\pdfstrcmp` (or XeTeX's `\strcmp` equivalent).

Is there a pure TeX definition of `\pdfstrcmp` that I could insert into the top of my file?  or is this not possible?

Comment: Use LuaTeX instead of your old eTeX and program in Lua.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is 'no'. The longer version is that this primitive (almost certainly) cannot be implemented in macros: primitives rarely can be. In particular, `\pdfstrcmp` can do an expandable comparison of two sets of tokens on a character ('string') basis, without loosing any spaces. In the past, the LaTeX3 team did have some code which attempted to do the same thing using only (e-)TeX primitives, but there were limitations and we ended up with issues as a result. The availability of this primitive is very useful for a number of functions which otherwise cannot be implemented expandably, and the team therefore made a decision to require it in addition to those from e-TeX: it's been available for a number of years.

Comment: There was quite a bit of discussion about requiring this primitive: in the end the utility outweighed the narrowing of usable engines.

Comment: The problem being was that there was no way (or we couldn't see one) to emulate this in an expandable way. so the code we had was ok 95% of the time but in the remaining 5% it blew up badly. So if anybody comes up with an expandable implementation of this primitive using only e-TeX that would be interesting, but I seriously doubt this is possible, given that several people tried very hard already.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: How then was the primitive built?

Comment: @AhmedMusa a primitive is a command that is offered already by the engine. That particular one is part of pdftex since a couple of years back and under a different name by XeTeX. expl3 detects which engine it is running on and selects the right name to use.

Comment: Is it possible to briefly explain why \pdfstrcmp can't be defined in terms of Xetex's \strcmp?

Comment: @CharlesStewart `\strcmp` _is_ `\pdfstrcmp`: XeTeX addition of primitives from pdfTeX tend to drop the `\pdf...` part if they are not PDF-related.

Comment: @JosephWright - OK, this is clear now.