# Which engines can compare strings expandably?

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, strings

The pdfTeX engine introduces the primitive `\pdfstrcmp` for expandable string comparison, with the input itself fully expanded, for example

```
\edef\foo{\detokenize{foo}}
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\foo}{foo}=0 %
  \TRUE
\else
  \FALSE
\fi
```

As detailed in [\pdfstrcmp or \strcmp in pure TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111296/pdfstrcmp-or-strcmp-in-pure-tex), this (almost certainly) cannot be emulated completely in TeX90. The functionality therefore has to be provided by the engine itself. Which engines provide the equivalent of `\pdfstrcmp`?

Comment: @jfbu No problem :) There is a place for asking and answering questions 'for the public good' - I was surprised that this had not been covered before (but can't find it).

Comment: I have a spin-off question: I did some quick benchmarking but for this used `time` in a bash shell, hence needed to do many reps to make negligible engine, format, and packages loading time; I did this because I recall `luatex` does not support `\pdfelapsedtime`. Do you have a canonical answer also for `\pdfresettimer/\pdfelapsedtime`? (I find them useful to get rough order of magnitudes).

Comment: @jfbu I'll write something up later: in LuaTeX one can use Lua to emulate the timer primitives, whilst in XeTeX and (u)pTeX we are out-of-luck, at least without shell escape

Comment: @jfbu BTW, looking again here: the timer primitives will be in TL'19 pTeX/upTeX, and I have done the work for XeTeX, just waiting for my merge to be accepted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to pdfTeX itself, e-pTeX and e-upTeX provide the `\pdfstrcmp` primitive under that name. In XeTeX, the same idea is implemented as `\strcmp`: the lack of `pdf` reflects the fact this is not PDF-related. In LuaTeX, one can emulate the outcomes in Lua:

```
\directlua{
```

```lua
  local write = tex.write
  function strcmp(A,B)
    if A == B then
      write("0")
    elseif A < B then
      write("-1")
   else
     write("1")
   end
  end
```

```tex
}
\long\def\luaescapeexpandedstring#1{%
  \luaescapestring{\detokenize\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}}%
}
\long\def\luastrcmp#1#2{%
  \directlua{%
    strcmp("\luaescapeexpandedstring{#1}","\luaescapeexpandedstring{#2}")
  }%
}
```

Notice that we have to cover a couple of things here:

- Handling `#` tokens correctly requires a bit of work with expansion
- As well as the 'obvious' 'they are equal' outcome, one also needs to cover the
  'one is bigger than the other' outcome (useful for example if comparing
  large integer values of the same number of digits!)

We might therefore set up something like

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname ifdefined\endcsname\relax
  \ERROR
  \expandafter\endinput
\fi
\ifdefined\directlua
  \directlua{
```

```lua
    local write = tex.write
    function strcmp(A,B)
      if A == B then
        write("0")
      elseif A < B then
        write("-1")
     else
       write("1")
     end
    end
```

```lua
  }
  \long\def\luaescapeexpandedstring#1{%
    \luaescapestring{\detokenize\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}}%
  }
  \long\def\stringcompare#1#2{%
    \directlua{%
      strcmp("\luaescapeexpandedstring{#1}","\luaescapeexpandedstring{#2}")
    }%
  }
\else
  \ifdefined\pdfstrcmp
    \long\def\stringcompare#1#2{\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}}
  \else
    \ifdefined\strcmp
      \long\def\stringcompare#1#2{\strcmp{#1}{#2}}
    \else
      \ERROR
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
```

to define `\stringcompare` in an engine-neutral way (note I've avoided the primitive name as the number of expansions required is different from a macro wrapper).

Comment: +1. :-) If the `luacode` package is loaded, the `\luastring` macro -- which fully expands its argument -- may be employed. The main instruction in  the `\stringcompare` macro may then be simplified to `\directlua{strcmp(\luastring{#1},\luastring{#2})}`, and the `\luaescapeexpandedstring` macro needn't be defined. In order to make this approach engine-neutral, one would also have to write `\usepackage{luacode}` immediately after `\ifdefined\directlua`...

Comment: @Mico I don't usually use the `luacode` package, as other than toy applications it's better to put Lua in a separate file. Here, though, the issue would be that `\luastring` _doesn't_ handle`#` tokens in the same way as `\pdfstrcmp` (`\luastring` is just a wrapper for `\luaescapestring`): you do need to do the more careful manipulation involving `\expanded` and `\detokenize` to get the same result in all cases.

Comment: @Mico Try `\ifnum\stringcompare{#}{\detokenize{#}}=0 \TRUE\else\FALSE\fi` using `\luastring` ;)

Comment: Many thanks -- I wasn't aware until now of these shortcomings of the `\luastring` macro.

Comment: @Mico We (the LaTeX team) spotted this one a while ago when picking up the code from `pdftexcmds`: it showed up in the test suite. We fixed in it the `expl3` version, which is what I've written in 'normal' names my answer!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74983/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-wright-which-engines-can-compare-strings-expandab).

Comment: I added some code to enable Lua-specific code highlighting; feel free to revert if you don't think it's an improvement.