# how can I compare strings using the if statement without package?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

For example,

```
\newenvironment{genPage}[2]
  {\clearpage\thispagestyle{#1}\normalsize\bfseries
    \if#2=c
        \centering
    \fi
  }
{\newpage}

\begin{document}
    \begin{genPage}{plain}{c}
    Some text...
    \end{genPage}
\end{document}
```

It is obvious that what I want to do is understood...
Thanks in advance

EDIT: I'm sorry, I still have a problem. When I leave empty the arguments of the environment, the macros \pagestyle{empty},\centering,\bfseries also apply

```
\newenvironment{genPage}[3]{%
    \clearpage
     {%
        \newcommand{\tempmacroe}{\detokenize{e}}%
        \newcommand{\tempmacroE}{\detokenize{#1}}%
        \newcommand{\tempmacrob}{\detokenize{b}}%
        \newcommand{\tempmacroB}{\detokenize{#3}}%
        \newcommand{\tempmacroc}{\detokenize{c}}%
        \newcommand{\tempmacroC}{\detokenize{#2}}%
        \expandafter
    }%

    \ifx\tempmacroe\tempmacroE
        \thispagestyle{empty}
    \fi
    \ifx\tempmacrob\tempmacroB
        \bfseries
    \fi
    \ifx\tempacroc\tempacroC
        \centering
    \fi
}{\newpage}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422741/which-engines-can-compare-strings-expandably perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A syntax such as

```
\genPage{}{}{}
```

is not what I'd call a good user interface, but it's your document.

```
\newenvironment{genPage}[3]
 {%
  \clearpage
  \edef\tempmacroe{\detokenize{e}}%
  \edef\tempmacroE{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \edef\tempmacrob{\detokenize{b}}%
  \edef\tempmacroB{\detokenize{#3}}%
  \edef\tempmacroc{\detokenize{c}}%
  \edef\tempmacroC{\detokenize{#2}}%
  \ifx\tempmacroe\tempmacroE
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \fi
  \ifx\tempmacrob\tempmacroB
    \bfseries
  \fi
  \ifx\tempacroc\tempacroC
    \centering
  \fi
 }
 {\clearpage}
```

The group you open before doing the `\newcommand` parts is wrong, because at the time the tests are performed the values of the `\tempmacroX` macros are forgotten. The `\expandafter` you have does nothing at all.

Since an environment forms a group by itself, the values of `\tempmacroX` will be forgotten as soon as `\end{genPage}` is executed.

Note that using `\newcommand{\tempmacroe}{\detokenize{e}}` and similar would work, but `\detokenize` would not act: in the first test you would compare the replacement texts of `\tempmacroe` and `\tempmacroE` which would be

```
\detokenize{e}
```

and

```
\detokenize{#1}
```

(with `#1` replaced with the actual argument), so the test would *fail* if by chance you end up with an argument `e` where `e` has not category code 11.

Using `\detokenize` (but with `\edef`) will ensure that the category code of the character used in the argument is irrelevant.

A different test would work as well, provided the argument is always a single token:

```
\if\detokenize{e}\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \pagestyle{empty}
\fi
```

This doesn't need defining `\tempmacroe` and `\tempmacroE`. If the argument is empty, `\if` would compare `e` with `\relax`.

With `pdflatex` you can also do

```
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{e}{#1}=0
  \pagestyle{empty}%
\fi
```

which is also independent of category codes and has the advantage of allowing

```
\newcommand{\thisisane}{e}

\begin{genPage}{\thisisane}{}{}
```

which will choose `\pagestyle{empty}`, because the arguments to `\pdfstrcmp` are expanded.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the `=` sign, or TeX will try to compare `#2` and `=`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{genPage}[2]
  {\clearpage\thispagestyle{#1}\normalsize\bfseries
    \if c#2%
        \centering
    \fi
  }
{\newpage}

\begin{document}
\begin{genPage}{plain}{notc}
  Some text...
\end{genPage}
\begin{genPage}{plain}{c}
  Some text...
\end{genPage}
\begin{genPage}{plain}{notcagain}
  Some text...
\end{genPage}
\end{document}
```

As jfbu noted the environment fails with `\begin{genPage}{plain}{cagain}`, making the output centered (as it probably shouldn't), and typesetting **`again Some text...`**. But it is obvious you know that ;)

Perhaps a safer approach that performs a token comparison with `\ifx`:

```
\newenvironment{genPage}[2]
  {\clearpage\thispagestyle{#1}\normalsize\bfseries
   {% group to restore tempmacroa and tempmacrob to whatever they were before
   \def\tempmacroa{c}%
   \def\tempmacrob{#2}%
   \expandafter}%
    \ifx\tempmacroa\tempmacrob
        \centering
    \fi
  }
{\newpage}
```

or, as Joseph suggested, a string comparison using `\detokenize`:

```
\newenvironment{genPage}[2]
  {\clearpage\thispagestyle{#1}\normalsize\bfseries
   {%
   \edef\tempmacroa{\detokenize{c}}%
   \edef\tempmacrob{\detokenize{#2}}%
   \expandafter}%
    \ifx\tempmacroa\tempmacrob
        \centering
    \fi
  }
{\newpage}
```

Comment: perhaps clarify that the `\if c#2` will compare `c` with the first token in `#2`, so with `cagain` the test is positive and leaves "again" in the token stream? (ending in typeset output)

Comment: Perhaps clarify that the `\ifx` test compares tokens? If you want strings, `\edef\@tempa{\detokenize{#2}}`, _etc._

Comment: Ideally, `\reserved@a`, _etc._, should _only be used by the kernel itself_

Comment: @JosephWright I didn't know that `\reserved@a` should only be used by the kernel, I thought they were _all-purpose_ temporaries. I didn't know what I expected from a macro which name is `\reserved` :P Thanks

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik That would be `\@tempa`, _etc._: they are called _reserved_ for a reason (bits of kernel code may rely on their state between different 'places').

Comment: @JosephWright Indeed, I already broke some things by using `\reserved@a`. Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: ok, removing my comments as egreg's answer is now there

Answer (score 1):

With your code `\detokenize` does never get carried out.
What is your intention when using it?

The empty line behind the closing brace yields a `\par`-token and
the `\expandafter`-token is applied to that.

You could probably do something like

```
\newenvironment{genPage}[3]{%
  \clearpage
  {%
    \def{\tempmacroe}{e}%
    \def{\tempmacroE}{#1}%
    \def{\tempmacrob}{b}%
    \def{\tempmacroB}{#3}%
    \def{\tempmacroc}{c}%
    \def{\tempmacroC}{#2}%
    \def\tempmacro{}%
    \ifx\tempmacroe\tempmacroE
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\tempmacro\expandafter{\tempmacro\thispagestyle{empty}}%
    \fi
    \ifx\tempmacrob\tempmacroB
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\tempmacro\expandafter{\tempmacro\bfseries}%
    \fi
    \ifx\tempacroc\tempacroC
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\tempmacro\expandafter{\tempmacro\centering}%
    \fi
  \expandafter}\tempmacro
}{\newpage}
```

As you tried to do with your snippet of code, the most straightforward approach for comparing two arbitrary brace-balanced token sequences is using each of them as *⟨replacement  text⟩* of another scratch-macro and `\ifx`-comparing the scratch macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\UnexpandableCheckWhetherTokenSequencesAreEqual[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\UD@tempa{#1}%
  \def\UD@tempb{#2}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \ifx\UD@tempa\UD@tempb 
     \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo
  \else
     \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \fi
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\UnexpandableCheckWhetherTokenSequencesAreEqual{Foo}{Bar}%
{Token sequences are equal.}%
{Token sequences are differing.}


\UnexpandableCheckWhetherTokenSequencesAreEqual{Foo}{Foo}%
{Token sequences are equal}%
{Token sequences are differing}

\end{document}
```

Pitfalls:

Routines like this one cannot be used in expansion-contexts like `\edef` or `\csname..\endcsname` as (re)defining scratch macros implies performing assignments while the tokens representing assignment do not get carried out at the stage of expansion.

After defining `\def\macro{A}`, `A` and `\macro` are taken for different things although expansion yields the same token-sequence.

Explicit character tokens are taken for something that is differing from their implicit pendants.

E.g., the character token `A` of catcode 11(letter) will be taken for something that is differing from the implicit-character-token `\A` which is defined via `\let\A=A`.

Explicit character tokens of one catcode are taken for something that is differing from their explicit pendants of differing catcode.

E.g., an `A` of catcode 12(other), which might come into being, e.g.,  due to `\string A` is taken for something that differs from an `A` of catcode 11(letter) which might come into being due to reading in the input and tokenizing an `A`-character.

---

For expandably comparing sequences of tokens whereof only one is not yet specified at the time of writing the comparison-routine and whereof the specified ones do not contain braces / do not contain explicit character tokens of category code 1 or 2, TeX' `\if`-primitives are not needed at all.

You can do it by using macros with delimited arguments, using those strings that are already specified as argument delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Paraphernalia
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
%%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument does not contain "!":
%%......................................................................
\newcommand\UD@GobbleToExclam{}%
\long\def\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!{}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!}%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Implement Forking depending on the argument holding specific strings:
%%......................................................................
%% For showing the gist of the mechanism, let's crank out the cases of
%% the argument being empty, of the argument being "AAA", of the 
%% argument being "BBB", of the argument being "CCC", of the argument
%% being "DDD", of the argument being "EEE", of the argument being
%% something else.
\newcommand\UD@StringFork{}%
\long\def\UD@StringFork#1!!AAA!BBB!CCC!DDD!EEE!#2#3!!!!{ #2}%
%%
\newcommand\StringFork[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam{#1}{%
     \UD@StringFork
       !#1!AAA!BBB!CCC!DDD!EEE!{Tokens in case argument is empty.}%
       !!#1!BBB!CCC!DDD!EEE!{Tokens in case argument is AAA.}%
       !!AAA!#1!CCC!DDD!EEE!{Tokens in case argument is BBB.}%
       !!AAA!BBB!#1!DDD!EEE!{Tokens in case argument is CCC.}%
       !!AAA!BBB!CCC!#1!EEE!{Tokens in case argument is DDD.}%
       !!AAA!BBB!CCC!DDD!#1!{Tokens in case argument is EEE.}%
       !!AAA!BBB!CCC!DDD!EEE!{Tokens in case argument is something else that contains no exclamation mark.}%
       !!!!%
  }{%
     Tokens in case argument is something else that contains an exclamation mark.%
  }%
  % The "Tokens in case..."-thingies can, e.g., be provided as arguments #2..#9 of
  % \StringFork.
  %
  % It is also feasible to let the "Tokens in case..."-thingies be numbers.
  %
  % When doing this, you can place the call to the \StringFork-macro as 
  % <numberK>-argument within the call to a macro
  %  \getKthArgumentOfLArguments{<numberK>}{<numberL>}%
  %     {Argument 1}%
  %     {Argument 2}%
  %     ...
  %     {Argument L}%
  % where L can be larger than 10.
  % 
  % When doing this, you can place the call to the \StringFork-macro as
  % <number>-argument within an \ifcase<number> ..\or ..\or ... \else...\fi-statement.

}%
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt\relax

\begin{document}

\medskip\verb|\StringFork{!AAA!BBB!CCC!DDD!EEE!}|:\\
\StringFork{!AAA!BBB!CCC!DDD!EEE!}

\medskip\verb|\StringFork{AAA}|:\\
\StringFork{A{A}A}

\medskip\verb|\StringFork{FooBar}|:\\
\StringFork{FooBar}

\medskip\verb|\StringFork{ }|:\\
\StringFork{ }

\medskip\verb|\StringFork{}|:\\
\StringFork{}

\medskip\verb|\StringFork{AAA}|:\\
\StringFork{AAA}

\medskip\verb|\StringFork{BBB}|:\\
\StringFork{BBB}

\medskip\verb|\StringFork{CCC}|:\\
\StringFork{CCC}

\medskip\verb|\StringFork{DDD}|:\\
\StringFork{DDD}

\medskip\verb|\StringFork{EEE}|:\\
\StringFork{EEE}

\end{document}
```

[image]