# How to add new primitives to e-TeX?

Tags: tex-core, e-tex

I am aware of this question [\pdfstrcmp or \strcmp in pure TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111296/pdfstrcmp-or-strcmp-in-pure-tex) so I want to learn how to add the missing primitive `\pdfstrcmp` to e-TeX. From LaTeX3 source code `expl3.lua`:

```
local function strcmp(A, B)
  if A == B then
    write("0")
  elseif A < B then
    write("-1")
  else
    write("1")
  end
end
l3kernel.strcmp = strcmp
```

it seems to me that the primitive `\pdfstrcmp` is basically a wrapper for standard C's `strcmp` function. So I believe there should be an easy way to "delegate" the WEB implementation to C (not using pure TeX like the aforementioned question). What is the procedure to add new primitives to an engine?

Comment: `\pdfstrcmp` is already present as primitive in pdfTeX, XeTeX has `\strcmp` as primitive and an implementation in Lua exists for LuaTeX (e.g., package `pdftexcmds`). What are you missing?

Comment: the `etex` engine is (these days) `pdftex` in dvi mode, so `\pdfstrcmp` is defined.

Comment: @Oberdiek I am using the *original* e-TeX that only output the DVI. I have a special need for it.

Comment: Of course, it would be of interest in case I need to add even more primitives for personal consumption.

Comment: there is no "procedure" (and historically it is rather rarely done) but pdftex is open source so you could in theory take https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/ copy the pdftexdir to ahoatexdir and then make a new engine with whatever changes you wanted to make and then promote that format over the existing pdftex format (see for example ptex with extra primitives for japanese typesetting)

Comment: @AnHoa where did you get etex from? the etex in miktex and texlive is based  on pdftex (although it makes dvi output)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use e-TeX source from TeX Live and compile it directly from source code by `make etex` for personal use.

Comment: @AnHoa `\pdfstrcmp` is independent from the output mode and can be used in DVI mode as well. The prefix `\pdf` comes from `pdfTeX`, not from PDF, and should avoid name clashes with existing macros.